Why does Poirot find "A Tale of Two Cities" to be funny?
In Murder on the Orient Express (2017), there is a scene where Detective Poirot is reading this book, "A Tale of Two Cities," which he apparently finds very funny. The shot and acting were deliberate to the point that I felt I was supposed to "get" something; however, as I am not really familiar with the work of either Christie or Dickens, or the deep lore of Poirot for that matter, whatever it was went over my head.
I have found an article and a thread where this scene is mentioned, but no answer or discussion as to what it means.

The thread you have linked to is very close to the answer:

...in the book, [Poirot] says "M. Harris will not arrive. I read my Dickens." The implication is that Harris is like Mrs. Harris in "Martin Chuzzlewit," a made-up character, and Poirot has intuited this because he is a reader of Dickens.

In the book, the murderers didn't want anyone else on the train, so they booked the final berth under a fictional name to keep anyone else from getting on.
Neither the 1974 film script nor the 2017 film script use this dialogue. Perhaps the fact that Poirot spots this ruse immediately may not have worked on film?
In the 2017 version, Poirot chuckling to himself while reading a different Dickens book is a way of alluding to the line without actually saying it. This doesn't really have any bearing on the plot, but could be regarded as an "easter egg" for those who are already familiar with the story.
